# Wireless Data Packet Capturing with help of scapy

Tags: python, security, wireless, scapy, intrusion-detection

My code That I have tried is as follows:

```
from scapy.all import *

def PacketHandler(pkt) :

       if pkt.haslayer == 2 and pkt.subtype==0:

          if pkt.haslayer(IP) :

             ip=pkt.getlayer(IP)
             print ip.dst

          if pkt.haslayer(UDP):
               udp=pkt.getlayer(UDP)
               print udp.dport
          if pkt.haslayer(TCP) :
               tcp=pkt.getlayer(TCP)
               print tcp.port

sniff(iface="mon0", prn=PacketHandler)
```

Using this, I want to capture all wireless DATA packets but I am getting only multicast ( IP/UDP) packets. So how can I get all DATA packet in my wireless network? I have disabled encryption on my access point for this (temporarily) so I can get access to the data in packets.

Comment: Can you see them with `wireshark` on `mon0`interface?

Comment: I think you have to sniff with promiscuous mode https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode Also, please note that NOT all the network adapters support promiscuous mode.

Comment: @OmidRaha: yes I can see them on wireshark on mon0 interface.....

Comment: @pss: Yes I have enabled promiscuous/ monitor mode using "airmon-ng start wlan0" command

Comment: Maybe you can use a better wireless network card.
I can't capture the data packets just because
mine is terrible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to handle only `Data` frames, and not `Management` and `Control` frames, then you can do this:

```
from scapy.all import *

def packet_handler(pkt) :
    # if packet has 802.11 layer, and type of packet is Data frame
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) and pkt.type == 2:
            # do your stuff here
            print(pkt.show())


sniff(iface="mon0", prn=packet_handler)
```

Also you can use `filter` option of `sniff` function to filter only `Data` frames to go to your `packet_handler` function:

```
from scapy.all import *

def packet_handler(pkt) :
    # if packet has 802.11 layer
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
        # do your stuff here
        print(pkt.show())

sniff(iface="mon0", prn=packet_handler, filter="type Data")
```

[Here](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/52391/80211-frames-starter-guide-learn-wireless-sniffer-traces), is a good list of `type` and `subtype` values for frames.